# Fragment detach method doesn't stop camera preview

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have this layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/DeepSkyBlue"
    tools:context=".MainPreviewActivity"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/clean_preview_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lvImageProcessChoices"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And in my activity I got this:

```
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        System.out.println("savedInstanceState is NOT null");
        return;
    }
    CleanPreviewFragment cleanPreviewFragment = new CleanPreviewFragment();
    processedPreviewFragment = new ProcessedPreviewFragment();

    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.clean_preview_fragment_container,cleanPreviewFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.detach(cleanPreviewFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.clean_preview_fragment_container, processedPreviewFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.attach(cleanPreviewFragment);

    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Now what this does, it start a camera preview (on the clean preview fragment), detaches it and replaces it with another preview which is my modified preview and then attaches it (the clean preview fragment) again.

*Detach(): Detach the given fragment from the UI. This is the same state as when it is put on the back stack: the fragment is removed from the UI, however its state is still being actively managed by the fragment manager.*

So I detach it, but the camera preview still goes on?

Because when the replace happens I can see a modified preview. Is that caused by the attach() method?

Comment: The fragment you in the end should be called last before comit. Also don't call addToBackStack method if you don't want to keep it     http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html

Comment: I find it quite funny that everyone is saying the same thing and yet the person who asks never responded. And...StackOverflow says above "This question has not received enough attention".  Irony perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

The fragment you want in the end should be called last before comit. Also don't call addToBackStack method if you don't want to keep it developer.android.com/intl/ko/training/basics/fragments/

Answer (score 3):

I had The same problem a week ago.But I solved this by using .replace() method.

Try below and i am 100% sure that you problem will be solved.

```
// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack if needed 
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

this for the reference of above code kindly open below link

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html

so Now your code will look like

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.clean_preview_fragment_container,cleanPreviewFragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
fragmentTransaction.detach(cleanPreviewFragment);

fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.clean_preview_fragment_container, processedPreviewFragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 2):

Why you replacing the fragment and then attaching the detached fragment ?

I think you should do like this :

```
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.clean_preview_fragment_container,cleanPreviewFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    fragmentTransaction.detach(cleanPreviewFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.clean_preview_fragment_container, processedPreviewFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 2):

`Detach(): Detach the given fragment from the UI.`
But I think the point is you just added `cleanPreviewFragment` and didn't commit yet, so `cleanPreviewFragment` wasn't in the UI hierarchy yet, so `detach` and `attach` will do nothing.

Maybe this will works:

```
// first, add cleanPreviewFragment to UI
fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.clean_preview_fragment_container,cleanPreviewFragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
// then create new transition and do your job
fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.detach(cleanPreviewFragment);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.clean_preview_fragment_container, processedPreviewFragment);
fragmentTransaction.attach(cleanPreviewFragment);

fragmentTransaction.commit();
```